# Generating Subtitles from audio file using speech Framework iOS

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, avplayer, subtitle, ios10

In my app i play the audios using url with the help of AvPlayer. Now i want to add the support of subtitles in it. iOS 10 introduces the [Speech framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) which help us to recognize the real time and recorded speech. As according to the apple:

"You can perform speech transcription of both real-time and recorded audio. For example, you can get a speech recognizer and start simple speech recognition using code like this:

```
let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioFileURL)
recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
     print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
})
```

Now i am looking for the way that how can i get the Subtitles in the form of string of currently playing audio using this speech framework. And how i shall be able to know that which dialogue is currently playing so that i can show exactly the same string on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In the segments portion of SFSpeechRecognition you can selectively identify the Subtitles you wish. To do this you need to parse the segments through a filter highlighting specific text.